# nginx php-fpm pools, multiple sites and multiple opcaches?

Tags: php, nginx, opcache

I have one server with 2 sites (distinctly different folders on the server) and I worry about seperating them. Currently they sit with the default settings for php-fpm, which I assume is a single fpm-pool (www) and I guess shared opcache? PHP version is 7.2.

Is it enough to split them into two different php-fpm pools to not worry about opcache issues between the two sites? Is there any resources on setting up opcache for two simultaneous sites? I would like to be able to clear the opcache of one site without affecting the other.

Comment: I'm just scratching the surface with php-fpm, but from what I read it certainly seems creating two pools would achieve that.